# lxml not getting installed on AWS Elasticbeanstalk instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lxml

I used **lxml** module in my code to parse AWS response. Locally it works awesome, but when i deploy this to AWS elasticbean instance, it throws errors against lxml. I tried these solutions:

1. included **lxml** to **requirements.txt** and it failed.
2. I accessed AWS instance n tried to install it directly and it failed.
3. I put the below line in .ebextensions/02_python.config.

   09_lxml:
   command: "wget http://lxml.de/files/lxml-3.3.4.tgz && tar -xzvf lxml-3.3.4.tgz && cd lxml-3.3.4 && /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python setup.py install"

   ## #command: "echo 'hello'"

   leader_only: true

It worked **once** on an instance, but on a new instance nothing is gonna work. Need your help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an additional file in your .ebextensions folder that installs the necessary libraries using yum. The "key" (AWS' term) you want to use is `packages`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    libxml2: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    libxslt: []
    libxslt-devel: []
```

This instructs the deploy script to install these packages using yum when your app is first being deployed.

It runs before the requirements.txt file is processed, so when pip is instructed to install lxml it should have the necessary libraries.

Please see AWS's Documentation on [Customizing Software on Linux Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) for more information.

I believe the packages listed above are the only requirements for lxml, but [read up carefully in lxml's online documentation to be certain](http://lxml.de/installation.html#requirements).

Answer (score 0):

First, update debian packages using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install By using

```
 sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

Using `apt-get install` , It installs all dependencies for `lxml`. Then, you can install `lxml` using `pip` also.

OR

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: actually we are on **centos**

Comment: So, It can be "yum install python-lxml"

Comment: **yum update**
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No packages marked for update.